# Where is my checkstyle report after I run "mvn site"?

Tags: maven, maven-3, checkstyle, maven-site-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.2.3 with the Checkstyle 2.13 plugin.  I have a multi-module project, and have this configuration in the parent pom …

```
    <reporting>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.13</version>
                            <reportSets>
                                    <reportSet>
                                            <reports>
                                                    <report>checkstyle</report>
                                            </reports>
                                    </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3</version>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

When I run “mvn site”, I get build success without errors or warnings.  A report file gets generated at target/site/index.html, but when I visit that page in a browser, I don’t see the check style reports. What’s worse, when I click on the links to each module under the “Project Modules” section, I get 404s.  Each link is going to target/site/module-N/index.html, however such a file is not generated.

**Edit:** Per the suggestion in the comments, I added this

```
    <distributionManagement>
            ...
            <site>
                    <id>sourceforge-snapshot-site</id>
                    <name>Snapshot Site</name>
                    <url>scp://shell.sourceforge.net/home/project-web/checkstyle/htdocs/snapshot</url>
            </site>
    </distributionManagement>
```

This is just a dummy entry to satisfy the suggestion, but even with putting this in, site:stage failed to correct the broken links.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven Site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin) has a FAQ entry ["Why don't the links between parent and child modules work when I run "mvn site"?](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/faq.html#Why_dont_the_links_between_parent_and_child_modules_work_when_I_run_mvn_site) which says that

> What "mvn site" will do for you, in a multi-project build, is to run
>   "mvn site" for the parent and all its modules individually. The links
>   between parent and child will not work here. They will however work
>   when you deploy the site. If you want to test this, prior to
>   deployment, you can run the [site:stage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html) goal as described in the [usage
>   documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/usage.html)
>   instead.

So it would sound like the behaviour you see is as expected.

Comment: Perhaps I need to edit my question, but is there any way to run "mvn site" locally and configure something so that links work?  It would be useful for our developers to be able to run reports before committing code or deploying sits.

Comment: @DaveA well... doesn't the `mvn site:stage` suggested in the answer do it? (and also, can't the developers just check the individual folders even if links don't work)

Comment: site:stage doesn't work unless you have a <distribution> tag set up.  Also, sure you coudl open each individual file, but htis question is purely about running a single command (after the appropriate configurations) and being able to access everything in one place.

Comment: the tag is `<distributionManagement>`. Is there some reason then that you can't have that?

Comment: Ok, I tried adding the distributionManagement tag (see my edit) with some dummy site info, but upon running "mvn site:site site:stage", the links I mentioned are still broken.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this

```
                    <distributionManagement>
                            <site>
                                    <id>localhost</id>
                                    <url>file:///${project.build.directory}/reports</url>
                            </site>
                    </distributionManagement>
```

and then running "mvn site:site site:deploy" allowed me to product a local report with all links in tact.  Beat you Maven!